# Spring Data repository and native query with Geometry return type

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data, postgis, hibernate-spatial

I'm creating a project that uses some spatial queries. 
I use Spring boot with spring data repositories and PostgreSQL with PostGIS extension as database.

I created this repository:

```java
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface AreaRepository extends CrudRepository<Area, Long> {

    /*
      extra queries for Area here
    */

    @Query(value="select st_intersection(" +
                ":base_layer ," +
                ":filter_layer" +
                ")", nativeQuery = true)
    Geometry geometryIntersectGeometry(@Param("base_layer") Geometry baseGeometry,@Param("filter_layer") Geometry filterGeometry);

}
```

It contains some queries for the Area entity. I also want to use some PostGIS functions to do some calculations, so I created geometryIntersectGeometry to call the st_intersection function from PostGis, this should return a geometry.

I set the hibernate dialect to PostGIS in the settings:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_db
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
```

And I have the dependencies for hibernate spatial:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
```

Calling the geometryIntersectGeometry function results in an error:

```
No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111,{}
```

How do I tell JPA/Spring Data to map the geometry (PostGIS type) response to a Geometry(com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry) object?

Comment: Hi @Bart Did you solve this problem? I have encountered similar problem. When using native query, I get this error. I tried to solve problem with jpql with casting dto, performance is at very poor level comparing to native query solution.

Comment: Hi @whitefang, I used the solutions shown below https://stackoverflow.com/a/52334089/3706961

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to fix it by writing a [custom implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/2.0.9.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) of the repository and register the type (thx Simon Martinelli)

repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface AreaRepository extends CrudRepository<Area, Long>, AreaGisRepository {

    /*
      extra queries for Area here
    */

}
```

interface:

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;

public interface AreaGisRepository {

    Geometry geometryIntersectGeometry(Geometry baseGeometry, Geometry filterGeometry);
}
```

and implementation:

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;
import org.hibernate.spatial.JTSGeometryType;
import org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PGGeometryTypeDescriptor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

public class AreaGisRepositoryImpl implements AreaGisRepository {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    public AreaGisRepositoryImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Geometry geometryIntersectGeometry(Geometry baseGeometry, Geometry filterGeometry) {
        return (Geometry) entityManager
                .createNativeQuery(
                        "select st_intersection(:base_layer , :filter_layer) as geom")
                .setParameter("base_layer", baseGeometry)
                .setParameter("filter_layer", filterGeometry)
                .unwrap(org.hibernate.query.NativeQuery.class)
                .addScalar("geom", new JTSGeometryType(PGGeometryTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE))
                .getSingleResult();
    }

}
```

It works perfect, but I now have a hard coded dependency on Postgis (not likely we will use something else, but ...)

Answer (score 1):

Have you added Hibernate Spatial?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

This has support for GIS data: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#spatial

Comment: yes I know, I have the dependancy. Sorry will add dependancies to the question.

Comment: Have a look at how to register types in Hibernate Dialect https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type/

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a simpler way to get this done. Hibernate Spatial registers a number of spatial functions for use in HQL/JQL. So the following should work

```
@Query(value="select intersection(" +
            ":base_layer ," +
            ":filter_layer" +
            ")")
Geometry geometryIntersectGeometry(@Param("base_layer") Geometry baseGeometry,@Param("filter_layer") Geometry filterGeometry);
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#spatial-overview) for a list of functions available in the Spatial Dialects.

Comment: Hi Karel, when I try that, it raises an exception:
    Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'intersection' {originalText=intersection}
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       +-[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=base_layer, expectedType=null}
       \-[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=filter_layer, expectedType=null}
 [select intersection(:base_layer ,:filter_layer)]

Comment: I tried it myself, and discovered two problems. The first is the "no data type for node" problem. This can be resolved by using an expression like this: 'select intersection( cast( :base as geolatte_geometry ), :test)' (the cast helps Hibernate to resolve the return type). The second problem is that HQL/JPQL requires a mapped entity. Can't see a good solution for this second problem. So your fix seems to be the best.